# mongodb TTL for collection (not document)

Tags: mongodb, ttl

Im using mongoDB through nodejs and I need to create temp collection.

can I create collection that will drop automaticlly after 30 minutes?
I saw I have TTL for documents, but it will not drop the collection (I will have an empty collection)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such feature available in MongoDB as of MongoDB 3.4.10.

A temporary solution would be to set up a scheduled task that runs approximately every minute, dropping a certain collection when some requirements are satisfied.

Having said that, there is a request for exactly this feature: [SERVER-18311](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18311).